# Reverse the String by using recursion

Tags: python

When I ran the code, the console showed the `TypeError` was:

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "unicode") to list

```py
class Solution(object):
    def reverseString(self, s):
        """
        :type s: List[str]
        :rtype: None Do not return anything, modify s in-place instead.
        """
        if len(s) == 0:
            return s
        else:
            return self.reverseString(s[1:]) + s[0]
```

Comment: What about how you're calling it? what do you pass in as `s` ?

Comment: `>>> sample = Solution()
>>> sample.reverseString("hello")
'olleh`
I don't get any error. Are you talking about specific case?

Comment: s is type s: List[str]

Comment: doc string says modify in-place, but Python strings are immutable, so in-place modification is impossible. and the method is returning str.

Comment: s[0] is a string, not a list use s[:1] instead

Comment: Sample input and ouput: Input: ["h","e","l","l","o"]
Output: ["o","l","l","e","h"]

Comment: @Munna When i tried [:1], the error becomes "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'list'"

Comment: return s if len(s)==1. it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is a list of strings and the question specifies not to return anything and modify the list in-place. In Python, strings themselves are immutable, but because lists are mutable you are able to essentially swap and move these elements around because they're in a mutable structure like a list.

Note: This also is able to be done in an iterative manner. Based on your example, I am showing a recursive sample.

```
x= ["h","e","l","l","o"]
def reverseString(s,start,end):
        """
        :type s: List[str]
        :rtype: None Do not return anything, modify s in-place instead.
        """
        if start > end:
            return

        # swap the ends if the indices are valid
        s[start], s[end] = s[end], s[start] 

        reverseString(s,start+1,end-1)

reverseString(x,0,len(x)-1)
print(x)
```

```
Output: ['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h']
```

Comment: A minor improvement: swapping variables can be done without using a temporary variable in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the same recursive function to do both **string** and **list** types, but in python, those types are different from each other related to concatenation. So, in this case you need to develop two different functions OR converting a list to a string or a string to a list.

This could do both implementations:

```py
class Solution(object):
    def reverseString(self, s):

        """
        :type s: List[str]
        :rtype: None Do not return anything, modify s in-place instead.
        """
        if len(s) == 0:
            return s
        else:
            return self.reverseString(s[1:]) + s[0]
    def reverseList(self, l):
        if len(l) == 0: return []
        return [l[-1]] + self.reverseList(l[:-1])

instance = Solution()
mystring = "hello"
mylist = ['h','e', 'l','l','o']
print(instance.reverseList(mylist))#['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h']
print(instance.reverseString(mystring))#olleh
```

Answer (score 0):

As s[0] is string type, it cannot be concatenated to list. Change to this:

```
    if len(s) == 0:
        return s
    else:
        return self.reverseString(s[1:]) + [s[0]]
```

and the problem's solved.